# Domain registration not showing the correct expiry in whois and it is shown for sale when we visit it. Is there a conflict?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, whois

Our group registered one domain (say for example `mysite.example`) as it was shown available on various domain registrars. Registration went successfully on online payment. Even after few weeks it is also showing in registrar's 'Your domains' correctly.

However, if we check its 'whois', it shows with other bulk domain registrar with its expiry shown in December,2018 whereas we have registered the domain for few years.

If we visit that referred domain say `mysite.example`, that bulk registrar shows the banner "for sale" there.

How can our registrar and other registrars were showing it as available in this case and successfully registered it too ? Will we loose this domain due to registration conflict ?

Comment: Give the name if you want relevant help. There are so many misconceptions and errors and how the whole thing work and proper use of tools that there is no point discussing without the name. Things even change per TLD, and you give absolutely no indication...

Comment: There can not be any "registration conflict". The domain can only be registered once (or not at all) and then various tools online may give you false information. The only true source of information is the **registry** database which you can (often but not always, which is why discussion without a specific name is worthless) query in near real time using the `whois` protocol/tool when targeting the **registry** whois server.

Comment: Also: where did you register it? Did you do a specific and separated domain registration through a registrar you double checked is accredited with the registry, or did you use any provider and service package? Do you have an invoice showing that the domain name was registered. Also as silly/obvious as it may look like, double check for typographical errors, swapping two letters happen, as well as registering `color` instead of `colour` or the opposite and things like that. Same for the TLD.

Comment: Please provide a link to perfectly check registry database. I will let you know domain name in your inbox. I have registered it through znetlive.com. Due to complication mentioned before, I was hesitant to publicly disclose the domain name.

Comment: "znetlive.com" does not seem to be a registrar and if you have an issue with something you purchased from them, maybe you should first try to ask them about it? If you want help here, give the details asked for in previous comments, otherwise there is nothing that can be done, as your question is too vague.

Comment: As suggested by Alston, I was getting stale results from whois. Your line of actions was also very useful, @PatrickMevzek. If you had answered instead of comment, I might have accepted your answer. Several of your comments helped in understanding how should I resolve and learned a lot about DNS things and how propagation works. Thanks a lot for your time through repeated answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue can be because most of the bulk domain checker or whois will show only partial records or not up to date so it can cache result which has previously checked and show it.

If you have registered it and have full access to domain then you don't need to worry.

Comment: We have only registered that domain. If you visit that domain, it should go to parked page of MY registrar in that case or if they have not parked it, it will generate error "server at xyz.com" not found. It goes to "for sale" banner of other registrar is what creates doubt that somebody else might indeed be holding that domain until Dec, 2018 as it shows. What will happen if they renew it before expiry ?

Comment: @RajeshKakkad who is domain registrar? Did you buy domain using backorder? or is it domain auction? also have you contacted the your registry's support staff.

Comment: I bought domain after checking availability through various registrars. It was regular buy, not through backorder or auction. I was confused about contacting registrar or to wait until the previous domain registration expires in Dec as shown in whois. If domain registrar cancel registration then I loose chance to wait for the date of expiry on previous registration. Hope I am clear.

Comment: @RajeshKakkad who is the domain register?